# Pasar datos de una fila (tabla) a otra pagina PHP

Tags: php, html

Busco su ayuda con el siguiente caso. Tengo una tabla HTML la cual cargo de manera dinámica desde mysql, cada fila de la tabla tiene un boton con el cual pretendo llevar los datos de la fila seleccionada a otra pagina y recoger los datos en un formulario y para esto utilizo un input hidden. El problema que tengo es que siempre me lleva el ultimo registro de la tabla a la siguiente pagina y no el que selecciono. Este es el código de mi tabla:

```html
<form action="servicio.php" method="post">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Ticket</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach($consultaTicket as $datos): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $datos->getTicket(); ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $datos->getCliente(); ?>
                                    </td>
      <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="<?php echo $datos->getTicket(); ?>">
      <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Seleccionar"></td>
                                    <?php 
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
</form>
```

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar, no se que hacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada uno debe ser único, puedes usar identificadores únicos o formularios independientes por tupla para que el submit envíe los datos de su correspondiente formulario. Como sólo quieres los datos de la tupla te pongo un ejemplo con el segundo caso.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <th>Ticket</th>
     <th>Nombre</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <?php foreach($consultaTicket as $datos): ?>
       <form action="servicio.php" method="post">
         <tr>
           <td>
              <?php echo $datos->getTicket(); ?>
           </td>
           <td>
              <?php echo $datos->getCliente(); ?>
           </td>
           <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="<?php echo $datos->getTicket(); ?>">
           <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Seleccionar"></td>
        </form>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona de maravilla..Gracias

Comment: @wico No hay de que :), márcala como respondida para que no quede pendiente